# My session just exists in 1 minute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

i don't know why my code is not work correctly

```html
<system.web>
  <pages validateRequest="false"></pages>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" defaultLanguage="c#"></compilation>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="90000" />
</system.web>
```

i set timeout="90000" but it lost after 1 or 2 minutes

and then i do this code but it doesn't work too

```js
function heartBeat() {            
            $.get("KeepAlive.aspx?", function (data) { });            
        }

        $(function () {            
            setInterval("heartBeat()", 1000 * 30); // 30s send a request            
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

timeout's unit is milisecends, so 90000 is 1.5 minute !

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx they said unit is minute. Thank for your help